# Geo Nodes: fill a volume with random-sized cubes

Tags: geometry-nodes

does anyone know how to turn any object into random sized cubes?

Example:[image]

I'm not the best with geo-nodes but I have an idea about how to do it but I need some guidance.
I Think I'll need to use instances on points and random scale but I don't know how to fully do it.

Comment: For same-sized cubes, you'd probably use the Remesh modifier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see on the reference, the cuboids overlap:

[image]

This makes the effect very easy to achieve:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, that's exactly what I meant I missed some nodes and you added them.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be solved with non-overlapping random-scale cubes.

P.s. "non-overlapping" = axis-oriented integer-style

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, they clearly are overlapping, though :P

Comment: cool concept but they are indeed overlapping

Comment: @JoxXx What else did you expect? Either this way or "honest" blocks – the amount of geometry will not change much. And removing internal or overlapping geometry would take unnecessarily heavy calculations.

Comment: It's a nice effect, I was just making sure people don't get unnecessarily confused. A non-overlapping method could be possible, using a simulation zone maybe (but if it's supposed to be animated, with the deforming base, then that's a problem). One more idea: fill the volume with points (base for instancing cubes), but then merge some points at random on one axis (e.g. $z$, could be allowed by temp. scaling the point cloud), mark which points were merged to replace them with vertical cuboids, maybe repeat the process, spawn cuboids, scale each cuboid down on a single, random axis…